# base url redirecting for absolute urls

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, radix

I'm dealing with an annoying problem. I have to make some changes to a large website, which source code is not under my control (sub-contracting). As usually I try to rebuild a local copy of the site to test my changes. The problem is now that almost all paths used in URLs for images, css, links etc. are relative paths pointing to the root directory, like

href="/style/main.css"

This is a problem because I develop on an intranet server and I put this project into a nested directory, so the URL to the project files is sth. like

http://myIntranet.com/checkout/project

What happens is that the paths from the first example don't resolve correctly. So I tried using the base tag to set the directory from which links should be resolved as

That works fine when the path is

href="style/main.css"

without the slash at the start, but fails when the slash exists, because (I think) the link is resolved from the server host, not from the URI in the  tag.

So... is there any possibility to make the "/dir/file.html" links resolve from a root othe than the server root? Or do I have to manually remove all prepending slashes from the paths (urgh)?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing local development on a web site you can do either of the below. Both involve moving your project in a base folder instead of working with sub folders inside your document root.

**Virtual host on different port**

In your web server, create another [listening port](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) and [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html).

After restart, you can access your web server as `http://localhost:81` or whatever port number you choose.

**Virtual host on same port**

Only create another virtual host (like above), but make sure to use named virtual hosting.

After restart, you have to add another entry in your hosts file (`c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` or `/etc/hosts`) using a simple text editor:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost myproject1.self.com
```

The above line should already exist, so you can keep adding more names to it:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost myproject1.self.com myproject2.self.com
```

**Personal preference**

I like the second option, because I don't have to mess with ports and stuff like Facebook API keeps working as you expect.

I hope this all makes sense, let me know otherwise.

Comment: thank you Jack. Would like to try the 2nd option but confused. Any chance you can provide an idiot proof example. thanks

Comment: What are you confused about? I can add many details but it might just be one you need.